# How to translate comment field label?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I'm using the Russian localization for Drupal sites and everything seems to be finely translated **except** the comment form (while viewing a node).

The field "**Subject**" is translated but the field label "**Comment**". I mean, comment's body field displays as "Comment". And what's interesting, I cannot find it in the translation list (for manual translation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit content type > comment field > edit > change the text

[image]